# FileStream: used by another process error

Tags: c#, .net, file-io, filestream

I have two different modules that need access to a single file (One will have ReadWrite Access - Other only Read). The file is opened using the following code in one of the modules:

```
FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(@"D:\post.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
```

Th problem is that the second module fails while trying to open the same file using the following code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\post.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Do I need to set some additional security parameters here?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

On the FileStream that only READS the file, you need to set it as

`FileShare.ReadWrite`

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\post.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

other wise the original FileStream would not be able to write back to it...its just a volley back and forth between the two streams, make sure you hand back what the other needs

Comment: +1: OK it worked but I dont know why. Will the first FileStream be able to save while the second one is open?

Comment: With a quick test, I was able to write to the first then close the stream all while the other was open and has the CanRead status return true....so looks that way, yes

Comment: Note that even if you open FileAccess.Read , you need to specify the FileShare.ReadWrite , if another one opened this with FileShare.ReadWrite already. All the FileStreams must have the same FileShare Mode.

Answer (score 1):

When opening the second `FileStream`, you also need to specify `FileShare.Read`, otherwise it will try to open it with exclusive access, and will fail because the file is already open

Comment: Tried that but it did not work: FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\post.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the filestreamname.Open(); and the filestreamname.close(); command when using 2 filestreams that read/write to the same file, because you can't read and write to a file asynchronously.